# how to change the enumeration in tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

Hello I have **3 boxes** that come from the code configured as "**boxex**" and the fourth of another color named "**boxe**", here my problem:

I want to take the reference number of the **third** box "**boxex**" to use it in the fourth box, **first of** "**boxe**" and so on for the following boxes or 4th box "**boxex**" with 2nd box "**boxe**".

Now I have 2 possible ideas and consists in that the enumeration is manually and the other is that I have to take it from the label reference.

But I do not know how to do it, can you help me?

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{boxex}[2][]{fontupper=\footnotesize,
colback=black!40,colframe=black,fonttitle=\bfseries,sharp corners,
title=\thetcbcounter~#2}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{boxe}[2][]{fontupper=\footnotesize,
colback=black!20,colframe=green!30!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,sharp corners,
title=\thetcbcounter~#2}

\title{Example tcolorbox enumerate}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
    \section{code tcbox}
    \begin{boxex}{Title one}
    Hi, it's my box one
    \end{boxex}
    \begin{boxex}{Title two}
    Hi, it's my box two
    \end{boxex}
    \begin{boxex}{Title tree}
    Hi, it's my box tree
    \end{boxex}
    \begin{boxe}{Change counter ``thee''}
    Hi, this is where I want to change the enumeration to \bf{3}
    \end{boxe}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand correctly you want `boxe` environments with the number of the `boxex` environment before it. That can be achieved by leaving the `boxe` environments unnumbered (by removing `auto counter` from the box options), and inserting the counter of the `boxex` environment in the title definition of `boxe`.

The counter is stored as `\thetcbcounter` inside of the box, but inside another box this refers to the counter of the new box instead of the original box - in this case, inside `boxe` the counter `\thetcbcounter` refers to the counter of `boxe` but you want to refer to the counter of `boxex`. However, the macro `\thetcbcounter` is a shortcut for an internal counter name which is unique for the type of box. Example 5.1 on page 110 of the [tcolorbox manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) states that "the real counter name is `tcb@cnt@pabox`" for the box type `pabox`. So in your case the counter of `boxex` is stored as `tcb@cnt@boxex`.

Now, given that this counter name contains the `@` symbol, it is not allowed to use this in regular code (this is by design, internal parts of the code are not intended to be used in documents, only in the package code itself). You can access this type of macros by surrounding code using the macro with `\makeatletter` and `makeatother`, i.e., make the `@` symbol a normal symbol, use it as a normal symbol, make it a special symbol again. We can use this to define a new macro, without `@` in the name, to refer to the `boxex` counter and define the title of the `boxe` macro using the new counter macro. A counter can be printed by putting `\the` in front, so the counter `tcb@cnt@boxex` can be printed using `\thetcb@cnt@boxex`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

% define helper macro to refer to boxex counter
\makeatletter
\def\boxexcounter{\thetcb@cnt@boxex}
\makeatother

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{boxex}[2][]{fontupper=\footnotesize,
colback=black!40,colframe=black,fonttitle=\bfseries,sharp corners,
title=\thetcbcounter~#2}

% use helper macro in title definition of boxe environment
% don't use auto counter for this environment
\newtcolorbox{boxe}[2][]{fontupper=\footnotesize,
colback=black!20,colframe=green!30!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,sharp corners,
title=\boxexcounter~#2}

\title{Example tcolorbox enumerate}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
    \section{code tcbox}
    \begin{boxex}{Title one}
    Hi, it's my box one
    \end{boxex}
    \begin{boxex}{Title two}
    Hi, it's my box two
    \end{boxex}
    \begin{boxex}{Title tree}
    Hi, it's my box tree
    \end{boxex}
    \begin{boxe}{Change counter ``thee''}
    Hi, this is where I want to change the enumeration to \bf{3}
    \end{boxe}
    \begin{boxex}{Title four}
    Hi, it's my box tree
    \end{boxex}
    \begin{boxe}{Change counter ``thee''}
    Hi, this is where I want to change the enumeration to \bf{4}
    \end{boxe}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply @Marijn, is perfect